# Failed to Create Development Service Fabric Cluster on Windows Server 2016 Standard

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am attempting to create a local development (unsecured) Service Fabric Cluster on Windows Server 2016 Standard. I have followed the instructions found in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/). However, I'm getting a rather interesting error and cannot find anything to help me resolve this.

> FabricHostSvc was not installed by FabricInstallerSvc on machine
>   localhost. FabricSetup may have failed. CreateCluster Error:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Fabric.FabricServiceNotFoundExc eption: FabricHostSvc was not
>   installed by FabricInstallerSvc on machine localhost. FabricSetup may
>   have failed.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.StartAndValidateInstallerServiceCompletion(Str
>   ing machineName, ServiceController installerSvc)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallel Options, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOption s, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithE verything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.RunFabricServices(List`1
>   machines, FabricPacka geType fabricPackageType)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__7.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Fabric.FabricServiceNotFoundException: FabricHostSvc was not
>   installed by FabricInstall erSvc on machine localhost. FabricSetup may
>   have failed.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.StartAndValidateInstallerServiceCompletion(Str
>   ing machineName, ServiceController installerSvc)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )<---
>
> Cleaning up faulted installation. FabricRoot not found in registry of
>   target machine localhost. Create Cluster failed. For more information
>   please look at traces in FabricLogRoot. Create Cluster failed with
>   exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> System.AggregateExcep tion: One or more errors occurred.    at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String
>   clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabric PackageSourcePath, Boolean
>   cleanupOnFailure)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__0.MoveNext()<---

Has anyone encountered this error before and fixed it? How is this error resolved?

**Side Note:** After receiving this error I ran the *CleanFabric* PowerShell script and removed all the Service Fabric files from the server and tried running the installation again with the same error message.

In addition, there are no Service Fabric SDKs installed on the machine (the ones you'd use on a local development machine). The reason for this is due to the official prerequisites stated by Microsoft shown below.

```
Prerequisites for each machine that you want to add to the cluster:

 1. A minimum of 16 GB of RAM is recommended. 
 2. A minimum of 40 of GB available disk space is recommended. 
 3. A 4 core or greater CPU is recommended. 
 4. Connectivity to a secure network or networks for all machines. 
 5. Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2012 (you need to
    have KB2858668 installed). 
 6. .NET Framework 4.5.1 or higher, full install. 
 7. Windows PowerShell 3.0. The RemoteRegistry service should be running on all the machines.

The cluster administrator deploying and configuring the cluster must have administrator privileges on each of the machines. You cannot install Service Fabric on a domain controller.
```

I cannot help but feel there is something obvious missing but I've followed the docs very closely so this is rather perplexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Fabric drivers have a signing issue which is preventing them from being installed on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 Anniversary edition. Please wait for the next version or try with version 5.2.

Comment: Correction, Please wait for the next version or use version 5.2.

Comment: I appreciate the information. I didn't see anything in that article or docs that indicated the driver signing issue. Hopefully they update it or people running into a similar problem see your answer without spending too much time scratching their heads trying to figure out why things aren't working.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the version correction. Also, I cannot find anywhere to download v5.2 except for at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/10/13/release-of-sdk-2-3-301-and-runtime-5-3-301-for-windows/. At the bottom it has download links applicable to Windows 10 Anniversary but I'm not sure if they are what I'm looking for in regards to Windows Server 2016 since those files use PowerShell scripts and install binaries that way. Any thoughts?